# Need help in bash scripting

Tags: bash, shell

I am new to shell scripting and I am encountering some issue with my codes. Currently, I have this line of code which is able to run perfectly on my terminal which will give me the result which I am looking for:

```
cat BookDB.txt | awk -F ":" '$1 ~ $Title'
```

However, when I try to implement this into my script, no result is shown. Anyone able to help me with this problem?

Comment: could you please post the contents of the text file, or preferably a few lines of it?

Comment: What do you mean "implement this into my script"?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Do you have something represented by $Title as input to the script, that you are trying to match?

Comment: Frankly, it's hard to believe that this runs "perfectly" at your terminal, if you enter it there the exact same way (same single-quoted attempt at variable expansion) you do here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is $Title supposed to be a shell variable? If so, the shell can't substitute it because the awk body is in single quotes. Use awk's `-v` option to pass shell variables into awk:

```
awk -F : -v "title=$Title" '$1 ~ title' BookDB.txt
```

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat

Comment: I wonder why there are so many [questions using the filename BookDB.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=BookDB.txt+is%3Aquestion)?